A question about the Paired samples
I am reviewing a few medical articles where the Wilcoxon signed-rank test was used for paired samples due to a lack of normality. However, the results were presented based on mean and standard deviation, along with the calculated p-value. I am wondering if this way of presenting the results is correct, given that the Wilcoxon signed-rank test (and not the paired t-test) was used. Additionally, it seems the Wilcoxon signed-rank test is not for comparing the medians. Could you please explain the hypothesis corresponding to this test?

Note that the paired t-test doesn't assume the paired variables themselves are normally distributed - only the population of differences are assumed to be normal. Further, for deriving the critical values (and hence for correctness of significance level), normality of the pair-differences is only assumed under $H_0$; the test can work very well under a much broader range of  circumstances for the alternative.
At the same time I'd suggest that testing normality of the sample differences is not a particularly good strategy on several fronts (it attempts to answer the wrong question in at least two senses, for one thing).
Normality is almost always strictly false in practice and large samples will show you that it is false. This is beside the point, however. Normality is a model, not a fact about the world. The questions we would be concerned with for the suitability of the test would be whether the actual significance level is close enough to the nominal one for our purposes (specifically, that the rejection rate doesn't go more than a very small amount above our selected $\alpha$ when $H_0$ is true) and whether the power of the test would be reasonable for the alternatives of interest. These questions can be addressed to a degree but are not questions about the  sample we want to use the test on.
It seems interest was originally focused on the mean of the  population of possible pair-differences, and that question of interest was only abandoned when there was some doubt about the assumption of normality.

However, the results were presented based on mean and standard deviation, along with the calculated p-value.

Certainly the p-value for the signed rank test is not based on a comparison of sample means. Placing adjacent to sample means would be potentially misleading unless that fact was made quite clear.
Nor does it test for a difference in means unless specific assumptions (beyond those needed to derive that  the test doesn't exceed its nominal type I error rate under the null, which are usually what people call "the assumptions") are made under the alternative to make it so. These would typically be assumptions that also make it a test for equality of any 'typical' location parameter - specifically, that there is a pure location shift under the alternative.
Such assumptions are not often likely to be true in practice, though the test will still have power against mean shifts. The problem is that the test focuses of different aspects of the distribution than the mean and may miss a shift in mean or may pick up a difference when the mean has not changed, or may even identify a shift in the opposite direction to the direction the mean changed in.
It seems most odd to change the population parameter about which we're hypothesizing like this, especially when we might even flip the direction of the effect by doing so. Given the trouble and expense of a study like this, it's strange to care so little about the original hypothesis that we potentially don't even care what size or even direction we conclude that its in relative to what direction of alternative we started with.
It's easy enough to test for a shift in mean of pair differences without assuming normality (or, with strictly positive measurements, a shift in the ratio from 1, or many other quantities of interest).
Usually I'd advise beginning with considering a more careful framing of exactly what population quantity we're interested in making inference about, and a more suitable parametric model for the variable of interest (at study-design time). Then, if necessary, a good test for that might be robustified or made nonparametric, generally while retaining good power near the parametric assumptions and retaining a relatively scientifically/clinically meaningful interpretation of the results.
If we were somehow in a position of complete ignorance about the behavior of our variable or ones that would be similar to it (a circumstance I find difficult to imagine), we could use data to help choose a reasonable model  but the appropriate way to do that would be to gather additional data and  split off a subset for such a purpose rather than use the same data for model selection (and worse, choice of population parameter in a hypothesis) and inference about the parameter .

Could you please explain the hypothesis corresponding to this test?

It can be framed as a hypothesis about the population pseudomedian (the population version of the one-sample Hodges-Lehmann estimator). A number of posts on site discuss this; one such example is here, it might be worth trying a few searches for more information.
That is, if our variable of interest is the original pair-differences ($D_i = Y_{2,i}-Y_{1,i}$ this is looking at the median of Walsh-averages (pair-averages, including self-pairs) of the population of values. The Walsh averages are $W_{i,j} = \frac12(D_i+D_j)$ for all $i\leq j$ (note the equality there); inference would then be on the median of the population distribution of $W$'s. My notation and description here might be somewhat loose or at least potentially misleading; with a continuous population process we can't simply enumerate the possible 'population pairs' as that might have suggested to you. However, the corresponding population pseudomedian can be defined in a mathematically formal way that corresponds to considering all such  potential pairs from the joint distribution.
Many stats packages will give both a point estimate and an interval for this population parameter, based on the corresponding sample quantity.
If the population of pair-differences is symmetric, then the pseudomedian and median will coincide. This won't necessarily be the case under the alternative unless you add further assumptions. That is, the pseudomedian of the differences  is not necessarily a consistent estimator of the median difference under $H_1$ unless you add assumptions to make it so; the test works perfectly well under a broader class of assumptions and in some cases it's possible to identify that the obvious assumptions to make to get that to happen won't apply.

First, thank you so much for your time and advice. I missed some points in your comment. Suppose the p-value after running the Wilcoxon signed-rank test is P<0.03. Can the results be presented as: “The cholesterol levels also improved from a mean of 312±87μm to 287±71μm, P<0.03”?
Is there any possibility (for example, under specific conditions) that the Wilcoxon signed-rank test can be used for checking the equality of means?

@ Glen_b, Additionally, could you please explain a bit more about why testing the normality of the sample differences is not always a good strategy? You mentioned that it might not address the right questions and can be misleading.
